# How to change the clock text in keith-wood jQuery Countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using keith-wood Jquery countdown. My sample code is as follows

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.countdown.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>


<script>
$(function () {
 var austDay = new Date();
 austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
 $('.countdown1').countdown({until: austDay});      
        $('.countdown2').countdown({until: austDay, format: 'HMS'});
});
</script>

Countdown1:
<div class="countdown1"></div><br/><br/><br/>

Countdown2:
<div class="countdown2"></div>
```

I want to change the clock text for the second div only. For example, i want to replace Hours into Hr, Minutes into Min and Seconds into Sec only for countdown2.

Comment: Did you tried referring this: http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need this:

Set the `labels:` as per your requirement as follows while initializing your `countdown`:

```
labels: ['Years', 'Months', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hrs', 'Min', 'Sec']
```

```js
$(function () {
 var austDay = new Date();
 austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
 $('.countdown1').countdown({until: austDay});      
        $('.countdown2').countdown({labels: ['Years', 'Months', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hrs', 'Min', 'Sec'], until: austDay, format: 'HMS'});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.countdown.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
Countdown1:
<div class="countdown1"></div><br/><br/><br/>

Countdown2:
<div class="countdown2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you `vijayP` for helping me.